# laravel excel jobs stuck and wont run

Tags: php, excel, laravel

i am using laravel excel package to export a query on queue .
on my console when i run
`php artisan horizon`
i see the jobs like below :

```
php artisan horizon
Horizon started successfully.
[2022-02-14 18:09:25][3733] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueExport
[2022-02-14 18:09:26][3733] Processed:  Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueExport
```

and nothing more . it just freeze here and not acting any thing else untill my next request then 2 to 5 jobs run and freeze again . any one has any idea how can i trace log or fix this ?
my excel code is an export like below :

```
 public function query()
    {
        \Log::critical('Query');
        return Order::query()
            ->when($this->request['from'], function ($query)
                return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->request['from'], $this->request['to']]);
            })
;
    }
public function map($row): array
    {
   return [
            $row['id']
]
}
   public function failed(Throwable $exception): void
    {
        Log::critical('Failed Export '.$exception->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: It's not freezing, it's completing. `Processed` means the job has finished running. Can you show your full QueueExport job?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this, if you are using a custom queue if you use:

```php
(new InvoicesExport)->queue('invoices.xlsx')->onQueue('exports');
```

like the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html#custom-queues) suggests for laravel 8+, it will only use the custom queue for the QueueExport job, you need to use `allOnQueue` for the custom queue to be used for the other jobs

```php
(new InvoicesExport)->queue('invoices.xlsx')->allOnQueue('exports');
```